# swift- playing a series of audio files

Tags: ios, swift

hi I want to play 5 audio files one after the other.

I have some code that will play one.

does anyone know how to play a group of audiofiles one after the other?

thanks

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

/* The delegate message that will let us know that the player
has finished playing an audio file */
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player: AVAudioPlayer!,
    successfully flag: Bool) {
        println("Finished playing the song")


}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    let dispatchQueue =
    dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)

    dispatch_async(dispatchQueue, {[weak self] in
        let mainBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()

        /* Find the location of our file to feed to the audio player */

   var x = 1


        let filePath = mainBundle.pathForResource("\(x)", ofType:"mp3")
    //    }

        if let path = filePath{
            let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)

            var error:NSError?

            /* Start the audio player */
            self!.audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(data: fileData, error: &error)



            /* Did we get an instance of AVAudioPlayer? */
            if let player = self!.audioPlayer{
                /* Set the delegate and start playing */
                player.delegate = self
                if player.prepareToPlay() && player.play(){
                    /* Successfully started playing */
                } else {
                    /* Failed to play */
                }
            } else {
                /* Failed to instantiate AVAudioPlayer */
            }
        }
     })

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ColiseuPlayer](https://github.com/ricardopereira/coliseu.ios.player), is an audio player framework written in Swift. It still in beta but you can use it or check the code.

Demo:

```
import UIKit
import ColiseuPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let player = ColiseuPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var list = [AudioFile]()

        if let urlFile = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("1.m4a", ofType: nil)!) {
            list.append(AudioFile(url: urlFile))
        }

        if let urlFile = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("2.m4a", ofType: nil)!) {
            list.append(AudioFile(url: urlFile))
        }

        if list.count > 0 {
            // Play first song (it will continue playing with the current playlist)
            player.playSong(0, songsList: list)
        }
    }
}
```